# Casting to List(Of T) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, generics, casting

In C# it's possible to cast to `List<T>` - so if you have:

```
List<Activity> _Activities;
List<T> _list;
```

The following will work:

```
_list = _Activities as List<T>;
```

but the translated line with VB.NET which is:

```
_list = TryCast(_Activities, List(Of T))
```

throws a compilation error. So I've had a good hunt around and experimented with LINQ to find a way round this to no avail.  Any ideas anyone?

Thanks

Crispin

Comment: You have an odd definition of "will work".  It may compile if you actually have a class named `T`, but then it will throw an `InvalidCastException` at runtime.

Comment: I've just taken a snippet out of Julie Lerman's Entity Framework book so I assumed that she had made it work.  Although I can read a lot of C#, there are some constructs that are still unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I repro, this should technically be possible.  Clearly the compiler doesn't agree.  The workaround is simple though:

```
    Dim _Activities As New List(Of Activity)
    Dim o As Object = _Activities
    Dim tlist = TryCast(o, List(Of T))
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
    Dim tlist = TryCast(CObj(_Activities), List(Of T))
```

The JIT compiler should optimize the temporary away so it doesn't cost anything.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just throw an `InvalidCastException`?

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. I'm following through Julie Lerman's Entity Framework book and there's a bit more work to be done before I have running code.

Comment: Hans! Thanks for your fix. I was able to fix this method and push through some of the other conversion oddities that the vb converting app could not work out and get the VB solution full working for Chapter 26 where this came from. It's available at http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/downloads/#2ed

Answer (score 1):

You can use the generic [List.ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28VS.90%29.aspx) method.

Given a List the method will return a List of a different type using a converter function you supply.

The MSDN article I linked has an excellent example.

Answer (score 0):

I always use `DirectCast(object, type)`